# How to use token id(value) from html response in jmeter correlation

Tags: selenium, testing, jmeter

Just leaning correlation, Please help me how to user token id under jmeter , i am using token id then getting error,

Please help me.

Website link is : https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/
and credentials : ( Username : Admin | Password : admin123 )

Attached images for reference purpose.

[image]

Comment: Show your Json extractor configuration

Comment: this is request:POST https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php/auth/validateCredentials

POST data:
actionID=&hdnUserTimeZoneOffset=5.5&_csrf_token=a835427641afe9c7916d3221328f245c&txtUsername=Admin&txtPassword=admin123&Submit=LOGIN

Cookie Data:
PHPSESSID=ubo8lut3ajcvu17073c2msn6d6

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: this is response data token info:                                                                                          <form id="frmLogin" method="post" action="/index.php/auth/validateCredentials">
        <input type="hidden" name="actionID"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="hdnUserTimeZoneOffset" id="hdnUserTimeZoneOffset" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="a835427641afe9c7916d3221328f245c" id="csrf_token" />        <div id="logInPanelHeading">LOGIN Panel</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is not JSON, it's normal [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) so you should be using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) in order to get the value of the `_csrf_token` hidden [input field](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Design your test plan as follows:

1. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which will send simple [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request to the https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/ page
2. Add CSS Selector Extractor as a child of the above request
3. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: `tokenid`
   - CSS Selector Expression: `form[id=frmLogin] > input[id=csrf_token]`
   - Attribute: `value`

     Demo:

     [image]
4. Add the request which is at your screenshot to be **after** the first GET request

See [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) article to learn more about handling dynamic data in your JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks alots, issue fixed able to login.

Comment: @dmritri T, can you plz let me know how to use regular expression extractor for this problem , is there any solution wrining this regular expression like this :   Regular expression: name="_csrf_token" value="(.+?)" id="csrf_token" and variable : token and template : $1$.                         Please help me.         Thanks,